# problems with Python Django NSException

Tags: python, html, django, web, frontend

I am working on a project using `Django` and `Python` and I am trying to plot a simple graph using `matplotlib` and I keep getting the error shown below.

`Python` also crashed after that.

I am using `mac` if that helps.

`Matplotlib` version '3.1.0'

I have already tried using the most simple graphs but still the problem persists.

This is my code in the **views.py** file

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
import random

def get_svg(request):
    t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
    s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(t, s)

    ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)',
               title='Sample')
    ax.grid()

    response = HttpResponse(content_type = 'image/png')
    canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(fig)
    canvas.print_png(response)
    return response
```

This is the error message I get:

```
2019-06-28 12:04:14.327 Python[76334:18290303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread!'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff41da1cf9 __exceptionPreprocess + 256
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6c936a17 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff41dbb859 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   AppKit                              0x00007fff3f3f1e26 -[NSWindow(NSWindow_Theme) _postWindowNeedsToResetDragMarginsUnlessPostingDisabled] + 317
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff3f3ef253 -[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 1479
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff3f3eec86 -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 45
    6   _macosx.cpython-37m-darwin.so       0x00000001107cf6b0 -[Window initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:withManager:] + 80
    7   _macosx.cpython-37m-darwin.so       0x00000001107d2bc7 FigureManager_init + 327
    8   Python                              0x00000001059f7087 wrap_init + 12
    9   Python                              0x00000001059be7ca wrapperdescr_call + 337
    10  Python                              0x00000001059b8af4 _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 358
    11  Python                              0x0000000105a4de20 call_function + 746
    12  Python                              0x0000000105a46b9a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6439
    13  Python                              0x00000001059b9068 function_code_fastcall + 112
    14  Python                              0x00000001059b99ed _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 150
    15  Python                              0x00000001059f6ff5 slot_tp_init + 80
    16  Python                              0x00000001059f3c98 type_call + 172
    17  Python                              0x00000001059b8af4 _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 358
    18  Python                              0x0000000105a4de20 call_function + 746
    19  Python                              0x0000000105a46b9a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6439
    20  Python                              0x00000001059b9068 function_code_fastcall + 112
    21  Python                              0x0000000105a4de27 call_function + 753
    22  Python                              0x0000000105a46b9a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6439
    23  Python                              0x0000000105a4e6d3 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1867
    24  Python                              0x00000001059b88c1 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 441
    25  Python                              0x00000001059b99ed _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 150
    26  Python                              0x00000001059b8d9b PyObject_Call + 136
    27  Python                              0x0000000105a46e6d _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 7162
    28  Python                              0x0000000105a4e6d3 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1867
    29  Python                              0x00000001059b88c1 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 441
    30  Python                              0x0000000105a46e6d _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 7162
    31  Python                              0x0000000105a4e6d3 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1867
    32  Python                              0x00000001059b8c53 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 225
    33  Python                              0x0000000105a4de27 call_function + 753
    34  Python                              0x0000000105a46b9a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6439
    35  Python                              0x00000001059b9068 function_code_fastcall + 112
    36  Python                              0x0000000105a46e6d _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 7162
    37  Python                              0x00000001059b9068 function_code_fastcall + 112
    38  Python                              0x0000000105a4de27 call_function + 753
    39  Python                              0x0000000105a46c35 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6594
    40  Python                              0x0000000105a4e6d3 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1867
    41  Python                              0x00000001059b8c53 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 225
    42  Python                              0x0000000105a4de27 call_function + 753
    43  Python                              0x0000000105a46b9a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6439
    44  Python                              0x00000001059b9068 function_code_fastcall + 112
    45  Python                              0x00000001059b99ed _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 150
    46  Python                              0x00000001059f65fb slot_tp_call + 71
    47  Python                              0x00000001059b8af4 _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 358
    48  Python                              0x0000000105a4de20 call_function + 746
    49  Python                              0x0000000105a46c35 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6594
    50  Python                              0x0000000105a4e6d3 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1867
    51  Python                              0x00000001059b8c53 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 225
    52  Python                              0x0000000105a4de27 call_function + 753
    53  Python                              0x0000000105a46b9a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6439
    54  Python                              0x00000001059b9068 function_code_fastcall + 112
    55  Python                              0x00000001059b99ed _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 150
    56  Python                              0x00000001059f65fb slot_tp_call + 71
    57  Python                              0x00000001059b8af4 _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 358
    58  Python                              0x0000000105a4de20 call_function + 746
    59  Python                              0x0000000105a46c35 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6594
    60  Python                              0x0000000105a4e6d3 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1867
    61  Python                              0x00000001059b8c53 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 225
    62  Python                              0x0000000105a4de27 call_function + 753
    63  Python                              0x0000000105a46b9a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6439
    64  Python                              0x00000001059b9068 function_code_fastcall + 112
    65  Python                              0x00000001059b99ed _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 150
    66  Python                              0x00000001059f65fb slot_tp_call + 71
    67  Python                              0x00000001059b8af4 _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 358
    68  Python                              0x0000000105a4de20 call_function + 746
    69  Python                              0x0000000105a46c35 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6594
    70  Python                              0x0000000105a4e6d3 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1867
    71  Python                              0x00000001059b8c53 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 225
    72  Python                              0x0000000105a4de27 call_function + 753
    73  Python                              0x0000000105a46b9a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6439
    74  Python                              0x00000001059b9068 function_code_fastcall + 112
    75  Python                              0x00000001059b99ed _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 150
    76  Python                              0x00000001059f65fb slot_tp_call + 71
    77  Python                              0x00000001059b8af4 _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 358
    78  Python                              0x0000000105a4de20 call_function + 746
    79  Python                              0x0000000105a46c35 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6594
    80  Python                              0x0000000105a4e6d3 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1867
    81  Python                              0x00000001059b8c53 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 225
    82  Python                              0x0000000105a4de27 call_function + 753
    83  Python                              0x0000000105a46b9a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6439
    84  Python                              0x00000001059b9068 function_code_fastcall + 112
    85  Python                              0x00000001059b99ed _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 150
    86  Python                              0x00000001059f65fb slot_tp_call + 71
    87  Python                              0x00000001059b8af4 _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 358
    88  Python                              0x0000000105a4de20 call_function + 746
    89  Python                              0x0000000105a46c35 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6594
    90  Python                              0x0000000105a4e6d3 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1867
    91  Python                              0x00000001059b8c53 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 225
    92  Python                              0x0000000105a4de27 call_function + 753
    93  Python                              0x0000000105a46b9a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6439
    94  Python                              0x00000001059b9068 function_code_fastcall + 112
    95  Python                              0x00000001059b99ed _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 150
    96  Python                              0x00000001059f65fb slot_tp_call + 71
    97  Python                              0x00000001059b8af4 _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 358
    98  Python                              0x0000000105a4de20 call_function + 746
    99  Python                              0x0000000105a46c35 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6594
    100 Python                              0x0000000105a4e6d3 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1867
    101 Python                              0x00000001059b8c53 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 225
    102 Python                              0x0000000105a4de27 call_function + 753
    103 Python                              0x0000000105a46b9a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6439
    104 Python                              0x00000001059b9068 function_code_fastcall + 112
    105 Python                              0x00000001059b99ed _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 150
    106 Python                              0x00000001059f65fb slot_tp_call + 71
    107 Python                              0x00000001059b8af4 _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 358
    108 Python                              0x0000000105a4de20 call_function + 746
    109 Python                              0x0000000105a46c35 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6594
    110 Python                              0x0000000105a4e6d3 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1867
    111 Python                              0x00000001059b8c53 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 225
    112 Python                              0x0000000105a4de27 call_function + 753
    113 Python                              0x0000000105a46b9a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6439
    114 Python                              0x00000001059b9068 function_code_fastcall + 112
    115 Python                              0x0000000105a4de27 call_function + 753
    116 Python                              0x0000000105a46b81 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6414
    117 Python                              0x00000001059b9068 function_code_fastcall + 112
    118 Python                              0x00000001059b99ed _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 150
    119 Python                              0x00000001059f65fb slot_tp_call + 71
    120 Python                              0x00000001059b8af4 _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 358
    121 Python                              0x0000000105a4de20 call_function + 746
    122 Python                              0x0000000105a46b9a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6439
    123 Python                              0x0000000105a4e6d3 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 1867
    124 Python                              0x00000001059b88c1 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 441
    125 Python                              0x00000001059b99ed _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 150
    126 Python                              0x00000001059f65fb slot_tp_call + 71
    127 Python                              0x00000001059b8af4 _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 358
    128 Python                              0x0000000105a4de20 call_function + 746
    129 Python                              0x0000000105a46c35 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6594
    130 Python                              0x00000001059b9068 function_code_fastcall + 112
    131 Python                              0x0000000105a4de27 call_function + 753
    132 Python                              0x0000000105a46b81 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6414
    133 Python                              0x00000001059b9068 function_code_fastcall + 112
    134 Python                              0x0000000105a4de27 call_function + 753
    135 Python                              0x0000000105a46b81 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6414
    136 Python                              0x00000001059b9068 function_code_fastcall + 112
    137 Python                              0x0000000105a4de27 call_function + 753
    138 Python                              0x0000000105a46b81 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6414
    139 Python                              0x00000001059b9068 function_code_fastcall + 112
    140 Python                              0x00000001059b99ed _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 150
    141 Python                              0x00000001059f6ff5 slot_tp_init + 80
    142 Python                              0x00000001059f3c98 type_call + 172
    143 Python                              0x00000001059b8af4 _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 358
    144 Python                              0x0000000105a4de20 call_function + 746
    145 Python                              0x0000000105a46b9a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6439
    146 Python                              0x00000001059b9068 function_code_fastcall + 112
    147 Python                              0x0000000105a4de27 call_function + 753
    148 Python                              0x0000000105a46b81 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6414
    149 Python                              0x00000001059b9068 function_code_fastcall + 112
    150 Python                              0x00000001059b99ed _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 150
    151 Python                              0x00000001059b8d9b PyObject_Call + 136
    152 Python                              0x0000000105a46e6d _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 7162
    153 Python                              0x00000001059b9068 function_code_fastcall + 112
    154 Python                              0x0000000105a4de27 call_function + 753
    155 Python                              0x0000000105a46b81 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6414
    156 Python                              0x00000001059b9068 function_code_fastcall + 112
    157 Python                              0x0000000105a4de27 call_function + 753
    158 Python                              0x0000000105a46b81 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 6414
    159 Python                              0x00000001059b9068 function_code_fastcall + 112
    160 Python                              0x00000001059b99ed _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 150
    161 Python                              0x00000001059b8d9b PyObject_Call + 136
    162 Python                              0x0000000105ab52b6 t_bootstrap + 71
    163 Python                              0x0000000105a7bcd8 pythread_wrapper + 25
    164 libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6e3522eb _pthread_body + 126
    165 libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6e355249 _pthread_start + 66
    166 libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6e35140d thread_start + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Could you please add the full error stacktrace? Maybe that contains important information of where and why the error originated.

Comment: edited with full error stacktrace!

Comment: Huh, that is a very strange stacktrace; never seen this format before. What version of Python are you using? Is your Django app started with `runserver` or a different HTTP server?

Comment: i am using 3.7.3 and yeah i started using `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: A [GitHub issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/14304) (from may 2019, currently still open) with the same symptoms...

Comment: how do you normally plot graphs using django? Do you have any examples or links to any tutorial?

Comment: I have used JavaScript plotting libraries most of the times (there are a lot of them to choose from). I expose the data as a `JsonResponse` from a Django view and the frontend does the actual plotting.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Mac.
Fixing it was as simple as specifying the "Agg" backend.

For example:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')  # Specify the Agg backend - this line resolves the error
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```